# iOS Objective-C Google map shows only on debug when added to a subview

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I'm using google maps SDK, first all was working fine but it was shown as a full screen. After adding the map into a subview, the map is no more shown. I added a breakpoint on the IBAction and noticed that after passing:

```
self.mapView1 = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:_subview.bounds camera:camera];
```

the map is shown perfectly in the subview.

Thats my code in IBAction:

```
GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:33.67 longitude:35.55 zoom:12];

self.mapView1 = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:_subview.bounds camera:camera];

self.mapView1.myLocationEnabled = YES;
[_mapView1 setMinZoom:12 maxZoom:20];
self.mapView1.mapType = kGMSTypeSatellite;
self.mapView1.settings.compassButton = YES;
_mapView1.delegate = self;
[_mapView1 animateToViewingAngle:45];

// Creates a marker in the center of the map.
GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(33.67, 35.55);
marker.title = @"City";
marker.snippet = @"Country";
marker.map = _mapView1;
[_subview addSubview:_mapView1];
```

[thats how i want it to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6hdmW.jpg)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add some screen shot to understand what you want to do?

Comment: @SiddheshMhatre screenshot added

Comment: try by replacing  self.mapView1 by _subview in your  IBAction code

Comment: same result after replace @SiddheshMhatre

Comment: did you added GMSMapView as class for  _subview ?

Comment: i was adding GMSMapView as class for mapView, now i have changed _subView to GMSMapView too but still it is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this it's working for me.

```
GMSMapView *customView = [[GMSMapView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 300, 100, 100)];
GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:33.67 longitude:35.55 zoom:12];

customView = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:customView.bounds camera:camera];

customView.myLocationEnabled = YES;
[customView setMinZoom:12 maxZoom:20];
customView.mapType = kGMSTypeSatellite;
customView.delegate = self;
[customView animateToViewingAngle:45];

// Creates a marker in the center of the map.
GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(33.67, 35.55);
marker.title = @"City";
marker.snippet = @"Country";
marker.map = customView;
[self.view addSubview:customView];
```

OR

```
GMSMapView *customView = [[GMSMapView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 300, 100, 100)];

GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:33.67 longitude:35.55 zoom:12];
_mapView = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:customView.bounds camera:camera];

_mapView.myLocationEnabled = YES;
[_mapView setMinZoom:12 maxZoom:20];
_mapView.mapType = kGMSTypeSatellite;
_mapView.settings.compassButton = YES;
_mapView.delegate = self;
[_mapView animateToViewingAngle:45];

// Creates a marker in the center of the map.
GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(33.67, 35.55);
marker.title = @"City";
marker.snippet = @"Country";
marker.map = _mapView;
[customView addSubview:_mapView];
[self.view addSubview:customView];
```

Also check your _subview hidden or not.

Comment: Yes i was trying it. thank u the first worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Since i can't comment, i will use this way to ask you to do some stuff:

1- Add a breankpoint to this line and check _subview.bounds values.

> self.mapView1 = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:_subview.bounds camera:camera];

2- While running in the simulator click on **Debug > View Debugging > Capture View Hierarchy** and locate your AVPlayer, check the properties on the right panel.

Answer (score 0):

Check the _subview.bounds when you are creating the GMSMapView.

Depending on the time this is done, it might not be setup and you can end-up with a CGRectZero frame.

Comment: where and when i should create it first?

Comment: Try in viewDidLayoutSubviews.

Comment: same nothing has changed :(

Comment: Put a breakpoint at self.mapView1 = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:_subview.bounds camera:camera]; and check the bounds.